# .NET User Agent parsing

Tags: .net, user-agent, string-parsing

Comparing the following User Agent strings for different browsers:

**IE8**

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 8.0**; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)

**Firefox 3**

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 **Firefox/3.6.16**

**Chrome 10**

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) **Chrome/10.0.648.204** Safari/534.16

---

I see there is consistency between Firefox and Chrome in displaying the Browser name (in bold in samples above), however IE shows it at an entirely different location in the string... **How does the HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase class parse this string? And how can I use this parser (or a custom one) to work with the Wurfl repository?** (E.g. I cannot find User_agent="IE6" anywhere in the repository while this is used on Win mobile)

*These are the variables from the .NET `HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase` class in the `Request` object.*

## IE8

```
Browser Capabilities Type = IE8
Name = IE
Version = 8.0
Major Version = 8
Minor Version = 0
Platform = WinNT
Is Beta = False
Is Crawler = False
Is AOL = False
Is Win16 = False
Is Win32 = True
Supports Frames = True
Supports Tables = True
Supports Cookies = True
Supports VBScript = True
Supports JavaScript = 3.0
Supports Java Applets = True
Supports ActiveX Controls = True
Supports JavaScript Version = 1.5
```

## Firefox 3

```
Browser Capabilities Type = Firefox3
Name = Firefox
Version = 3.6
Major Version = 3
Minor Version = 6
Platform = WinNT
Is Beta = False
Is Crawler = False
Is AOL = False
Is Win16 = False
Is Win32 = True
Supports Frames = True
Supports Tables = True
Supports Cookies = True
Supports VBScript = False
Supports JavaScript = 3.0
Supports Java Applets = True
Supports ActiveX Controls = False
Supports JavaScript Version = 1.8
```

## Chrome 10

```
Browser Capabilities Type = Chrome10
Name = Chrome
Version = 10.0
Major Version = 10
Minor Version = 0
Platform = WinNT
Is Beta = False
Is Crawler = False
Is AOL = False
Is Win16 = False
Is Win32 = True
Supports Frames = True
Supports Tables = True
Supports Cookies = True
Supports VBScript = False
Supports JavaScript = 3.0
Supports Java Applets = True
Supports ActiveX Controls = False
Supports JavaScript Version = 1.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at one of these resources:

- [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)
- [Browser Definition File Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx)
- [Recent changes in Google Chrome's user agent settings](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/03/changes-in-chrome-user-agent_31.html)

I once added my own browser definition file schema for exotic browsers (SeaMonkey)

Comment: In my question i refer to one of those resources. How do they match up? How should user-agent parsing be done?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question and did not see a reference to [MDN Browser Detection using the User Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). I found this to be very usefull when I was trying to detect browsers in ASP.NET because they even give a break down of what you should be able to parse for.